# Simple Titanum app throwing "KrollRuntimeThread msg:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load stlport_shared" error

Tags: android, titanium

I've created a number of TiStudio apps and pushed them to this device (HTC Incredible, Android 2.3.3) without issue.

But, starting today, any new apps crash with the following error:

```
I/TiRootActivity( 2122): (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity create, savedInstanceState: null
I/TiApplication( 2149): (main) [0,0] checkpoint, app created.
I/TiApplication( 2149): (main) [89,89] Titanium 2.0.1 (2012/04/12 16:36 999c68a)
I/TiApplication( 2149): (main) [265,354] Titanium Javascript runtime: v8
E/TiApplication( 2149): (KrollRuntimeThread) [25,379] Sending event: exception on thread: KrollRuntimeThread msg:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load stlport_shared: findLibrary returned null; Titanium 2.0.1,2012/04/12 16:36,999c68a
E/TiApplication( 2149): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load stlport_shared: findLibrary returned null
E/TiApplication( 2149):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
E/TiApplication( 2149):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
E/TiApplication( 2149):     at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.initRuntime(V8Runtime.java:55)
E/TiApplication( 2149):     at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime.doInit(KrollRuntime.java:163)
E/TiApplication( 2149):     at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:101)
I/TiRootActivity( 2149): (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity create, savedInstanceState: null
```

This includes the default app created by TiStudio or an even an app with just `Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');`

The strange thing is that my existing projects still work just fine, even after making code changes and recompiling.

Any idea what could cause this kind of behavior?